# I want draw a rectangle in MainActivity.java but my code can not draw a rectangle in main Activity

Tags: java, android, canvas

I want draw a rectangle in MainActivity.java but  my code can not draw a rectangle  and I added  only the following function

> public boolean draw(Canvas canvas)

it runs successfully but it can not draw a rectangle in main Activity.

> package com.examplee.pro;
>
> import android.os.Bundle; import android.app.Activity; import
>   android.view.Menu; import android.graphics.*;
>
> public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
> }
>
>
> @Override
> public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
>     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
>     return true;
> }
>
> public boolean draw(Canvas canvas){
>     Paint o = new Paint(); o.setColor(0);
>     canvas.drawRect(100,100,100,100,o);
>     return true;
> } }
> ```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Can not draw as in doesn't show up?

Comment: Can I write this code only and only in MainActivity.java and only in a file?

Comment: What I've done in the past (and I'm not sure if its standard) is create a custom view class, and overridden the draw method. Sure you can fudge the one file thing with a nested class, but it's still going to be two classes. The activity and the View

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to write your code in the onDraw method.

Although, I am not sure how you can use the canvas.I am sure you can but I never used it.However, here is a helpful link that will get your job done for sure.Just take the time and read it,everything is detailed and clear!

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html